# Create windows shortcuts

Tags: c#, windows, wsh

I am writing windows program to create shortcuts and having some difficult time.

The problem that I am facing is with special characters. When my path has special characters like "ü" and "Ş" program fails to create shortcut and gives an error message.

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: The system cannot find the path
>   specified.

I did further analysis and here is what happen,

If my path has a folder "Ravi - Ş" Shortcut API tries to create a file under "Ravi - S" folder which is little weird. Obviously, the folder does not exist and fails to create a shortcut. If I manually create the folder with "Ravi - S" and then run the program, shortcut created successfully under "Ravi - S" folder which is not the expected behavior.

So what I feel that Shortcut API is doing something extra which replaces these special characters.

Is it possible to create shortcuts with these special characters?

```
string MY_DOCUMENTS_PATH = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
path = string.Format("C:\\Ravi\\Ravi - Ş\\test.lnk", MY_DOCUMENTS_PATH);
networkPath = @"\\ravi.companyname.com\urlpart1\urlpart2\";
description = @"link description";

CreateLink(path, networkPath, description);
```

Below is the function to create shortcuts.

```
private static void CreateLink(string path, string networkPath, string description)
{
    try
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(path)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Path exists");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Path does not exists");
        }

        IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShell shell = new IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShell();
        IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(path);
        shortcut.Description = description;
        shortcut.TargetPath = networkPath;
        shortcut.Save();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error while creating shortcut");
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```